Boot specifies UUID, but is it the correct one?
I am having trouble with dual booting ubuntu. Getting error such as this:

I have tried mounting using a USB live version and updating grub and initframs and such, but I had no luck. I now wonder if the problem lies in my grub.cfg file.

cause here it looks like it "points" to the Linux uuid and not the EFI/boot partition. Is it supposed to have the UUID of the partition with the boot files? or the "linux files".
Results of blkid:


The search command is definitely supposed to point to UUID of the "linux" partition, not the EFI partition, and not its PARTUUID. In your grub.cfg it points to /dev/nvme0n1p6.

So should I replace the path /dev/nvme0n1p6 with the uuid or is everything in the grub.cfg correct and the problem lies else where? Furthermore how would i change it since when launching using a usb-live everything seems to be write protected.

I would change the UUID in the grub.cfg and reboot. At the time of a live boot from a USB stick, the file system is probably mounted read-only (check with mount, look for the ro flag). Unmount it and remount it with -o rw to make it read-write.

I changed the boot option (pressing e while in grub menu) and changed it to root=UUID=56ea45ae-acf8-47f5-9a37-f742e5c9a881 https://imgur.com/a/xOpoAOF
This resulted in a black screen ... I also tried chaning ext2 to ext4 (since the error says to specifiy - this also didin't work saying that ext4.mod doesnt exist)

I have also found the /etc/apt/sources.list to be empty could this be a problem? and how would i solve it?

No, that is not a problem, until you want to apt update your system.

Your grub.cfg as shown does not have the initrd line?
